# Given a coordinate in 2D clipspace, how can i sample the background texture

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

Consider a texture with the same dimensions as gl.canvas, what would be the proper method to sample a pixel from the texture at the same screen location as a clip-space coordinate (-1,-1 to 1,1)? Currently i'm using:

```
//u_screen = vec2 of canvas dimensions
//u_data = sampler2D of texture to sample
vec2 clip_coord = vec2(-0.25, -0.25);
vec2 tex_pos = (clip_coord / u_screen) + 0.5;
vec4 sample = texture2D(u_data, tex_pos);
```

This works but doesn't seem to properly take into account the canvas size and **text_pos** seems offset the closer **clip_coord** gets to -1 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following is assumed that the texture has the same size as the canvas and is rendered 1:1 on the entire canvas, as mentioned in the question.

If `clip_coord` is a 2 dimension fragment shader input where each component is in range [-1, 1], then you've to map the coordinate to the range [0, 1]:

```c
vec4 sample = texture2D(u_data, clip_coord*0.5+0.5);
```

Note, the texture coordinates range from 0.0 to 1.0.

---

Another possibility is to use [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml). `gl_FragCoord` is a fragment shader built-in variable and contains the window relative coordinates of the fragment.

If you use [WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) respectively [GLSLES 3.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf),
then `gl_FragCoord.xy` can be use for texture lookup of a 2 dimensional texture, by [`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/texelFetch.xhtml), to get the texel which correspond to the fragment:

```c
vec4 sample = texelFetch(u_data, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);
```

Note, `texelFetch` performs a lookup of a single texel. You can think about the coordinate as the 2 dimensional texel index.

If you use [WebGL 1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/) respectively [GLSL ES 1.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf),
then `gl_FragCoord.xy` can divided by the (2 dimensional) size of the texture. The result can be used for a texture lookup, by `texture2D`, to get the texel which correspond to the fragment:

```c
vec4 sample = texture2D(u_data, gl_FragCoord.xy / u_size);
```

Comment: It would be great if You would explain also the difference between `texel` and `pixel` inside this answer.

Comment: @deblocker A texel or pixel is a fundamental unit of a 2D texture. There is no difference. In compare to a voxel, which is an element of a 3d texture.

Comment: you need to cast `gl_FragCoord.xy` to `ivec2` if you want to use it with `texelFetch` in WebGL2

Comment: I now see my question is severely lacking detail, but your answer has confirmed that i need to check my texture size is indeed what i'm expecting and clip_coord is actually in the range (-1,1). Cheers

Comment: The texture i'm sampling is a FBO texture i'm creating, would this make a difference?

Comment: @maeneak Not for the texture coordinates.